# Fractional truncation into deadlock SSMS

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, deadlock

In short:
I need to write data for the past 8 years to a database per quarter. Every quarter will be written in 9 batches. When I try to run the script over the 32 quarters (8*4) it randomly errors at one point. I get many "Fractional truncation" errors with a single deadlock mixed in.

Since the data is significantly large, I can't find the row that errors. IT WORKS when I redo the exact batch that gave the "fractional truncation" errors and deadlock errors. So there is no way to narrow the batch down to the problem.

The process takes several days (an issue for another time) so I can't monitor until it breaks, manually redo the batch, filter out duplicates, check if everything is in there and restart the other quarters.

In detail:
In the SQL Server database, I'm reading data from Table A into Python. I'm predicting column X and column Y. I'm dumping the data in table B, which is table A + columns X, Y and Z (timestamp).

My analysis:
Since the column types of the overlapping columns in A and B are the same, these shouldn't give a problem. In Python, I check for nans, extremes, lengths, and I even regex the floats to see if those fit in a decimal datatype. So those columns should not be an issue. The timestamp is just a date stamp and can be written as well. The X and Y columns are floating values and are also controlled with regex to fit in the decimal(7,2).

The issue probably isn't the data on itself, since the data can be written to the database when I redo the batch manually. What could be causing the fractional truncation? What could cause the deadlock error, is it even relevant? I'm 99.9% sure nobody is reading from this table since I'm one of the few that has access to it, and it's on the develop server. Is it because when I'm writing those batches SQL Server is doing something on the background while I am writing the next batch to the table?

Additional information:
The data I'm writing is around 8.5 million rows per quarter and around 14 columns. So nothing extreme.
Error:

```
Exception has occurred: DBAPIError x
(pyodbc.Error) ('01S07', '[01S07] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Fractional truncation (0) (SQLExecute); [01S07] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Fractional truncation (0) (SQLExecute); [01S07] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Fractional truncation (0) (SQLExecute); [01S07] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Fractional truncation (0) (SQLExecute); [01S07] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Fractional truncation (0) (SQLExecute); [01S07] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Fractional truncation (0) (SQLExecute); [01S07] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Fractional truncation (0) (SQLExecute); [01S07] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Transaction (Process ID 517) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. (1205); (SQLExecute); [01S07] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Fractional truncation (0) (SQLExecute); ...
```

Script to write to database:

```
def write_to_db(
    data,
    table,
    database,
    cred=cred,
    server=server,
    schema=schema,
    if_exists="append",
    index=False,
    chunksize=100,
):
    """
    purpose: Write data to the SSMS database system.
    input:
        data -- Dataframe containing data to write to server
        table -- Tablename to write to
        database -- database to login to
        cred -- file location of the login credentials
        server -- SSMS server you want to operate on
        schema -- Schema to use for writing
        if_exists -- how to handle existing tables with the same name.
        - Append means we just add new rows
        - Replace means the full table is replaced.
        - Truncate means all rows are deleted
            and then we append new rows without deleting table.
        index, chunksize -- Passed on to pandas method,
            for documentation see:
                https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html
    output:
        None
    """
    user, passw = get_info(cred)

    cn_str = (
        "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
        f"Server={server},1433;"
        f"Database={database};"
        f"UID={user};"
        f"PWD={passw}"
    )

    connection_uri = (
        "mssql+pyodbc:///?"
        f"odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(cn_str)}"
        "&autocommit=true"
    )
    engine = sa.create_engine(connection_uri, fast_executemany=True)

    # Check if table exists
    if if_exists in ["truncate", "append"]:
        with pyodbc.connect(cn_str) as con:
            with con.cursor() as cursor:
                if not cursor.tables(table=table, tableType="TABLE").fetchone():  # noqa
                    raise ValueError(
                        f"Object [{database}].[{schema}].[{table}] "
                        "does not exist"  # noqa
                    )

    # Truncate table, if required
    if if_exists == "truncate":
        with pyodbc.connect(cn_str) as con:
            with con.cursor() as cursor:
                query = f"truncate table [{database}].[{schema}].[{table}]"
                cursor.execute(query)
                if_exists = "append"

    data.to_sql(
        table,
        engine,
        index=index,
        schema=schema,
        if_exists=if_exists,
        chunksize=chunksize,
    )
    return None
```

Python 3.10.10
sqlalchemy 1.4.47
Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Added DDL Table A (source table):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [YourSchemaName].[YourSourceTable](
    [A] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [B] [bigint] NULL,
    [C] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [D] [int] NOT NULL,
    [E] [int] NOT NULL,
    [F] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [G] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [H] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [I] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [J] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [K] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [L] [int] NULL,
    [M] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [N] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [O] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [P] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Q] [decimal](15, 12) NULL,
    [R] [decimal](15, 2) NULL,
    [S] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [T] [date] NOT NULL,
    [U] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AnonymousTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [A] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [YourSchemaName].[YourSourceTable] ADD  DEFAULT ('TypeA') FOR [U]
GO
```

Table B (destination table):

```
USE [yourdatabase]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [python].[AVM]    Script Date: 18-8-2023 13:37:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [yourschema].[yourtable](
    A [bigint] NOT NULL,
    V [date] NOT NULL,
    W [decimal](7, 2) NOT NULL,
    X [int] NOT NULL,
    Y [int] NOT NULL,
    Z [int] NOT NULL,
    H [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    I [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    G [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    C [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    D [int] NOT NULL,
    F [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    J [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    K [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    ZZ [date] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: There is almost certainly no way anyone here can assist. You have to dig in and debug it.

Comment: Please share code snippet and environment information(python,SQL server version etc)if you can how you are retrieve and ingest data in another table. So that we can able to help here

Comment: Added some extra information. Regarding python script and versions.

@DaleK you say that I have to dig in and debug it, I tried to look where I could look. But I'm a little bit lost where I should search. Am I right in assuming that the problem most likely would be in SQL Server? If so, where should I search then?

Comment: You have to learn everything you can about those errors and the cause of them. Then see how that applies to your system and investigate. For the deadlock, inspect the deadlock graph to find the cause.

Comment: One thing can probably be said for certain: SSMS has nothing to do with it. SSMS, or SQL Server Management Studio, is just a client program for connecting to and managing SQL Server instances.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76927688/edit) your question to include the DDL for the source and destination tables? The `01S07 Fractional truncation` error is an ODBC driver error that could apply to `decimal` types, or it could just as easily apply to `date` or `datetime` types. One of the gotchas with SQL Server's `datetime` type is that it inherits the baggage of Sybase's original `datetime` type with 1/300th second resolution,  this has a habit of catching people out in new and sometimes surprising ways.

Comment: I added both DDLs. Since columns F and G are read from the source and put in the destination in the same format, those shouldn't be the culprits. Those are checked for nans, rounded to 2 decimals and checked with regex to see if they contain 2 decimals.

Possible suspects:
V: date format that indicates quarter i.e. 2023-01-01
W: column with 2 decimals. All values between 0 and 150, rounded to 2 decimals and regex checked for 2 decimals.
ZZ: date format that indicates last modification date i.e. 2023-08-18

Comment: Let's just say one more thing: I can't imagine an SQL process which needs several *days* to complete. There is almost certainly a faster way of doing this, probably using some kind of `BULK INSERT` solution.

Comment: 260 million rows with 15 columns that have to be inserted. On the python side of the flow I do predictions per 8.25 million rows and then insert them. So it's not purely inserting data, also some preparation and modelling is done per 8.25 million rows.

I will look into BULK INSERT though.

Comment: @Hestaron as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlexecute-function?view=sql-server-ver15#diagnostics official doc (SQLSTATE = 01S07) *Fractional truncation error* due to date datatype.

Comment: For bulk data Insert Pandas Data Frame Using SQLAlchemy there is parameter named method https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html